# Getting "key schema too big" error with LocalSecondaryIndexes wth DynamoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, indexing, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to create a DynamoDB table using the Node.js script shown below.  If I remove the *LocalSecondaryIndexes* block and delete the two attributes definitions that are no longer necessary after that removal, the code works fine and creates the table successfully.  But with that block as shown in the code below, I get the following error back from DynamoDB:

```
Unable to create table. Error JSON: {
  "message": "Key Schema too big.  Key Schema must at most consist of the hash and range key of a table",
  "code": "ValidationException",
  "time": "2019-02-13T19:45:34.482Z",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 29.475438988642534
}
```

**How can I fix this problem?**

Here's the code:

```
// Create the quizzes table in DynamoDB.
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  endpoint: process.env.AWS_ENDPOINT
});

var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

var params = {
    TableName : "Quizzes",
    KeySchema: [
        { AttributeName: "author_id", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
        { AttributeName: "quiz_id", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
    ],
    // Secondary key allows us to get all the different versions of a
    //  a particular quiz, referenced by quiz name, for all the available
    //  languages the quiz supports.
    LocalSecondaryIndexes: [
        {
            IndexName: "ForeignLanguageSupportIndex",
            KeySchema: [
                { AttributeName: "author_id", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
                { AttributeName: "quiz_name", KeyType: "RANGE" },  //Sort key
                { AttributeName: "language_code", KeyType: "RANGE" },  //Sort key
                { AttributeName: "quiz_id", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
            ],
            Projection: {
                ProjectionType: "ALL"
            }
        }
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        { AttributeName: "author_id", AttributeType: "S" },
        { AttributeName: "quiz_name", AttributeType: "S" },
        { AttributeName: "language_code", AttributeType: "S" },
        { AttributeName: "quiz_id", AttributeType: "S" }
    ],
    // Using on-demand provisioning (pay as you go, no pre-allocation).
    BillingMode: "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
};

dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to create table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Created table. Table description JSON:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each table/index must have 1 hash key and 0 or 1 range keys. If you need to query using multiple attributes, you can create multiple indexes or, if the data is hierarchical as yours is, you can combine multiple pieces of data into your sort key. (See this [AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/using-sort-keys-to-organize-data-in-amazon-dynamodb/) for an official example. See also the [Best Practices for Using Sort Keys to Organize Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-sort-keys.html).)

### How do I create the table?

You can create the index you need like this:

```
// Create the quizzes table in DynamoDB.
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  endpoint: process.env.AWS_ENDPOINT
});

var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

var params = {
    TableName : "Quizzes",
    KeySchema: [
        { AttributeName: "author_id", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
        { AttributeName: "quiz_id", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
    ],
    // Secondary key allows us to get all the different versions of a
    //  a particular quiz, referenced by quiz name, for all the available
    //  languages the quiz supports.
    LocalSecondaryIndexes: [
        {
            IndexName: "ForeignLanguageSupportIndex",
            KeySchema: [
                { AttributeName: "author_id", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
                { AttributeName: "quiz_name_language", KeyType: "RANGE" },  //Sort key

            ],
            Projection: {
                ProjectionType: "ALL"
            }
        }
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        { AttributeName: "author_id", AttributeType: "S" },
        { AttributeName: "quiz_name_language", AttributeType: "S" },
        { AttributeName: "quiz_id", AttributeType: "S" }
    ],
    // Using on-demand provisioning (pay as you go, no pre-allocation).
    BillingMode: "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
};

dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to create table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Created table. Table description JSON:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

### So what does my data look like?

Your object that you read/write would look something like this:

```
{
    author_id: "author1234",
    quiz_name: "DynamoDBExperienceSurvey",
    language_code: "en-us",
    quiz_name_language: "DynamoDBExperienceSurvey/en-us",
    quiz_id: "55dc0736-2fdf-11e9-b210-d663bd873d93",
    quiz_data: {
        ...
    }
}
```

### How do I perform my queries?

Here are the [key condition expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions) to get the data you need.

To get all surveys by a certain author, you can query your table or the LSI using only the hash key.

```
author_id = "theAuthorId"
```

To get all the language variants of a quiz based on the name, your key condition would be

```
author_id = "theAuthorId" AND begins_with(quiz_name_language, "theQuizName/")
```

In this case, it's important that you include the `/` (or whatever delimiter you use) at the end of the quiz name, or else "theQuizName" will also return results for "theQuizName2", "theQuizName3", etc.

Bonus: you can also query for all of the regionalized variants of a specific language by using the first part of the language code.

```
author_id = "theAuthorId" AND begins_with(quiz_name_language, "theQuizName/en-")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only have 1 hash key and 1 sort key...per table,  local secondary indexes (LSI), or global secondary indexes (GSI).

You either need to concatenate quiz_name, language_code, and quiz_id into a single string, or create multiple LSIs.

The choice depends on how you need to query the LSI.

Comment: I used this guide when building my code: https://www.dynamodbguide.com/local-secondary-indexes/ . That example has a hash key/sort key for the main KeySchema, and a hash key/sort key for the LSI.  Or am I not understanding the terminology?  I want the main key for direct access to a unique quiz, but the secondary index so I can find out all the available quizzes for a particular "author_id/quiz_name/language_code" triple.  In other words, given a unique quiz name authored by a particular user, scan for all the quizzes available in the different language versions available.

Comment: You need to create an attribute in your data model which is a single string containing your tuple. Ie. create a new attribute where the data looks like this: “author12335/mycoolquiz/en-us”. You can use the `begins_with` operation to query for a specific author or author/quiz.

Comment: @MatthewPope I get the gist of what you are saying but not how to code it.  Could you promote your comment to an answer with a Javascript code snippet showing the table definition?