# DynamoDb error Schema too big. Key Schema must at most consist of the

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I'm implementing dynamodb using golang but facing an error while creating the table below is my code that I'm using in my application and also posting the error that I'm facing

```
input = &dynamodb.CreateTableInput{
            AttributeDefinitions: []*dynamodb.AttributeDefinition{
                {
                    AttributeName: aws.String("uuid"),
                    AttributeType: aws.String("S"),
                },
                {
                    AttributeName: aws.String("user_id"),
                    AttributeType: aws.String("N"),
                },
                {
                    AttributeName: aws.String("card_id"),
                    AttributeType: aws.String("S"),
                },
                {
                    AttributeName: aws.String("bid_amount"),
                    AttributeType: aws.String("N"),
                },
                {
                    AttributeName: aws.String("bid_flag"),
                    AttributeType: aws.String("N"),
                },
                {
                    AttributeName: aws.String("added_time"),
                    AttributeType: aws.String("N"),
                },
                {
                    AttributeName: aws.String("updated_time"),
                    AttributeType: aws.String("N"),
                },
            },
            KeySchema: []*dynamodb.KeySchemaElement{
                {
                    AttributeName: aws.String("uuid"),
                    KeyType:       aws.String("HASH"),
                },
                {
                    AttributeName: aws.String("user_id"),
                    KeyType:       aws.String("RANGE"),
                },
                {
                    AttributeName: aws.String("card_id"),
                    KeyType:       aws.String("RANGE"),
                },
                {
                    AttributeName: aws.String("bid_amount"),
                    KeyType:       aws.String("STRING"), // this is wrong but I'm just testing it
                },
                {
                    AttributeName: aws.String("bid_flag"),
                    KeyType:       aws.String("STRING"),// this is wrong but I'm just testing it
                },
                {
                    AttributeName: aws.String("added_time"),
                    KeyType:       aws.String("STRING"),// this is wrong but I'm just testing it
                },
                {
                    AttributeName: aws.String("updated_time"),
                    KeyType:       aws.String("STRING"), // this is wrong but I'm just testing it
                },
            },
            ProvisionedThroughput: &dynamodb.ProvisionedThroughput{
                ReadCapacityUnits:  aws.Int64(5),
                WriteCapacityUnits: aws.Int64(5),
            },
            TableName: aws.String(tableName),
        }
    }
    result, err := dbSvc.CreateTable(input)
```

> ValidationException: Key Schema too big.  Key Schema must at most consist of the hash and range key of a table
> status code: 400, request id: b4f9453f-3032-458d-ab75-a08ee317c96b

From error I understood is in `keyschema` there is only one primary key and and one secandry(forigen key). But In my data there are three forigen keys and one primary so How can I implement it. If there is something wrong that I'm doing or I'm saying then please sorry I'm new to dynamodb. Please help me out from this.

Comment: I would recommend taking some time to read/view some of the many articles/videos on DynamoDB patterns. If you're looking for a place to start maybe try Alex DeBrie's blog.

Answer (score 0):

> In my data there are three forigen keys and one primary so How can I implement it

This question suggests that you aren't clear on the differences between NoSQL and SQL databases.  It looks like you're attempting to use a normalized data model (like you would with a SQL database) in DynamoDB.  This is not the way to use DynamoDB.

There's a lot of resources available online to teach NoSQL data modeling with DynamoDB.  I would recommend you take the time to learn more about NoSQL data modeling before going any further.  You will save yourself lots of time and frustration!

Start with [this talk by Alex DeBrie from the 2019 AWS Re:Invent conference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIQVJqiSUkE).  It's a fantastic resource to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at this answer:
[1]: [Getting "key schema too big" error with LocalSecondaryIndexes wth DynamoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54678479/getting-key-schema-too-big-error-with-localsecondaryindexes-wth-dynamodb)

Also when it comes to DynamoDB it is critical to understand what you data is going to look like up front to get your data model correct. In short a table can have a primary key (mandatory) with a range key (Not mandatory). On top of that you can have an LSI (Local Secondary Index) - this is where you have a new key that has the same primary key as the table (This is part of the table) OR you can have a GSI (Global Secondary index) key. This is where you have a key that has no relation to the table primary key. However GSIs are like tables on their own and you get billed for them as well so do not overuse them.